# Classic ASP Do while Loop only shows the last record

Tags: asp-classic

I have a recordset containing 3 records. I am using DO While loop in classic ASP in order to display all the records but the code below only shows the last record in the recordset.

```
<%Do While Not RS.EOF%>
  <div><%=RS.Fields("ID").value%></div>                 
  <div><%=RS.Fields("Title").value%></div>
  <div><%=RS.Fields("Description").value%></div>
    <%RS.MoveNext()
Loop%>
```

Can anyone tell me why that is happening? Is it something about the way I fill the recordset?

I know for sure it contains 3 records as RS.RecordCount returns 3.

Here is a code I use to create a dummy recordset and fill it with data:

```
With RS.Fields
  .Append "ID", adBSTR
  .Append "Title", adBSTR
  .Append "Description", adBSTR
End With
With RS
  .AddNew
  .Fields("ID")="1111"
  .Fields("Title") = "Test1"
  .Fields("Description") = "Test Description 1"
  .Update
End With

With RS
  .AddNew
  .Fields("ID")="2222"
  .Fields("Title") = "Test2"
  .Fields("Description") = "Test Description 2"
  .Update
End With

With RS
  .AddNew
  .Fields("ID")="3333"
  .Fields("Title") = "Test3"
  .Fields("Description") = "Test Description 3"
  .Update
End With
```

Comment: Are you properly advancing to the NEXT ROW before populating its cells with the respective data elements?

Comment: the code is posted. Am I?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [AddNew Method (ADO)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677536(v=vs.85).aspx)

> After you call the **AddNew** method, the new record becomes the current
>   record and remains current after you call the **Update** method. **Since the
>   new record is appended to the Recordset, a call to MoveNext following
>   the Update will move past the end of the Recordset, making EOF True.**

This is why it's happened.

When you need to list all of the records of a recordset after adding a new record, you need to be sure that the cursor at the begin.

To do that, call [MoveFirst](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee275529(v=bts.10).aspx) (`RS.MoveFirst`) before where your loop `Do While Not RS.EOF` starts.